# nth-child not working for my <li> tags

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

thanks for reading! Having some issues today with the nth-child selector...
Here's the HTML code, followed by the CSS...

The below is basically just a < ul > < li > thats repeated 3x i am trying to remove the right margin on the 3rd element but somehow my code just doesn't work. appreciate any advice!

```
<div id="RightContent">
<h4>Jewelry</h4>

<ul class="grid cs-style-1">

  <a href="#ProductDetail">
   <li>
    <figure>
     <img src="images/ring.jpg" alt="img01">
      <figcaption>
      <h3>Atlas® closed narrow ring in 18k rose gold with a diamond.</h3>
      <span class="price">800</span>
      <a href="#Cart"><span class="add">Add to Shopping Bag</span>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </li>
  </a>

  <a href="#ProductDetail">
   <li>
    <figure>
     <img src="images/ring.jpg" alt="img01">
      <figcaption>
      <h3>Atlas® closed narrow ring in 18k rose gold with a diamond.</h3>
      <span class="price">800</span>
      <a href="#Cart"><span class="add">Add to Shopping Bag</span>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </li>
  </a>

  <a href="#ProductDetail">
   <li>
    <figure>
     <img src="images/ring.jpg" alt="img01">
      <figcaption>
      <h3>Atlas® closed narrow ring in 18k rose gold with a diamond.</h3>
      <span class="price">800</span>
      <a href="#Cart"><span class="add">Add to Shopping Bag</span>
      </figcaption>
     </figure>
    </li>
  </a>
```

So I have a piece of code like that above, and my css goes something like

```
.grid {
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
max-width: 890px;
margin: 0 auto;
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
}

.grid li {
display: inline-block;
width: 278px;
margin: 0px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: left;
position: relative;
}

.grid li:nth-child(3n+3) {
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

The nth-child pseudo selector doesn't seem to be working. My 3rd < li > item still has a margin. Would appreciate if anyone can point me to what exactly is wrong here?

Thanks so much

Comment: Your markup is broken... `ul` cannot contain `a` as direct child.

Comment: Here is a fiddle to validate @SalmanA's comment http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/quqztn42/

Comment: @Brian: can i add your fiddle to my answer?

Comment: thanks so much ... ! i was trying this for an hour or so!!! should have posted this question way earlier!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector isn't working because each `<li>` is in an `<a>` tag, which means that each `<li>` is the *first child* of its parent.

First, your markup is invalid. The hyperlinks should be inside the `<li>` elements, not outside them; [only `<li>` can be a direct child of `<ul>`.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)

Once that's corrected, you can use the selector `.grid li:nth-child(3n+3)` to select the third item in each list.

Comment: OK, I checked again; given the broken markup the `li` would still be the direct child of `ul` (2nd, 5th and 8th).

Comment: @SalmanA It depends on how the browser handles [tag soup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_soup). For example, with the original markup, Chrome will [render what's given to it](http://jsfiddle.net/odf15wLh/) even though it's invalid: each `<a>` tag will be a direct child of the `<ul>` and will contain its own `<li>`, and the `li:nth-child(3n+3)` selector won't apply.

Comment: In this particular example the ul has empty `<a>` and `<li>` as its children (because the markup is broken in two places).

Answer (score 2):

removing the anchor `<a href="#ProductDetail">` tags inside `ul` will solve your problem

`ul` should not have a direct `<a>` child

[@BrianDillingham's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/quqztn42/)

Answer (score 0):

You have `li tag` inside `a tag` but you are assigning `nth-child` to **li** which is incorrect. You should do:

`.grid a:nth-child(3n+3) li{margin-right: 0px;}`

Comment: But suggestion is that don't use `a tag` as direct child of `ul`